# The meaning of "user cuts applied" reported by CPLEX?

Tags: terminology, cplex

I have been working on a combinatorial optimization problem which can be modeled as an integer linear programming. I implemented it as a c++ project in visual studio 2017 and CPLEX1271. Since there are exponentially many constraints, I implemented lazy constraints callback and user cuts callback. The results reported by CPLEX looks like:

```
Clique cuts applied:  1
Cover cuts applied:  4
Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  1
Zero-half cuts applied:  13
Lift and project cuts applied:  2
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  3
User cuts applied:  2116
Solution status         =       Optimal
Gap     =       0
Elapsed time    =       14.235
Objectvie value         =       16675
Number of nodes         =       57
Number of cuts  =       2116
```

I was wondering what's the meaning the entry `User cuts applied`. Is it the number of constraints added by both user cuts callback and lazy constraints callback, or only by  user cuts callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry "User cuts applied" reported in the log gives the number of constraints added
by both user cuts callback and lazy constraints callback.
The distinction between user cuts and lazy constraints is done only in the separation phase. Once the cuts are added to the problem, they are not distinguished anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’d also like to know how can I obtain the numbers of these two cuts, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks for your answer!
> I’d also like to know how can I obtain the numbers of these two cuts, respectively

Hello.
As I said, once the cuts are added to the problem, there is no distinction between user cuts and lazy constraints. Therefore, if you want to distinguish between number of user cuts and number of lazy constraints, you have to count them by yourself when you add them to the problem from the corresponding callbacks.
Note however, that in some cases the number of cuts you add from the callbacks might be greater than the number of "applied cuts" reported in the log. First, not all the user cuts/lazy constraints that the user tries to add are necessarily added to the problem (e.g., if the user tries to add duplicated cuts or cuts already present in the problem, they are not added). Second, if the user specifies that user cuts and/or lazy constraints can be purged, some of them might be added to the problem but then removed afterwards.
In other words, the number of "applied cuts" refers to the cuts that are present in the problem at the end of optimization, and not to the total number of cuts that were added to the problem during optimization.